# Как получить список записей, который были добавлены в БД?

Tags: mysql

Добавляю данные в БД

```
INSERT IGNORE chat (nickname,wmid,datecreated, message) VALUES
```

Как узнать какие данные добавились в БД а какие нет? Можно ли как то их вынести в переменную?

Comment: Перед добавлением выполнить соответствующий SELECT. Либо, если точность позволяет, смотреть по `datecreated`.

Comment: А через что именно вы добавляете данные ? В большинстве языков программирования библиотеки работы с БД позволяют получить количество обработанных записей. И оно будет 0 если ничего не вставилось, т.е. был дубль. В крайнем случае, если библиотека не позволяет, можно воспользоваться `SELECT ROW_COUNT()` для получения этого количества